# CodeSignal Arcade level-4-16:"Are Similar?"

Tags: java

i passed all test cases,
but i failed in hidden casese.
I really can't find error cases and what's wrong with my code.
please help me

The question was as follows:

> Two arrays are called similar if one can be obtained from another by swapping at most one pair of elements in one of the arrays.
>
> Given two arrays, check whether they are similar.
>
> Example
>
> For A = [1, 2, 3] and B = [1, 2, 3], the output should be
> areSimilar(A, B) = true.
>
> The arrays are equal, no need to swap any elements.
>
> For A = [1, 2, 3] and B = [2, 1, 3], the output should be
> areSimilar(A, B) = true.
>
> We can obtain B from A by swapping 2 and 1 in B.
>
> For A = [1, 2, 2] and B = [2, 1, 1], the output should be
> areSimilar(A, B) = false.
>
> Any swap of any two elements either in A or in B won't make A and B
> equal.
>
> +) Guaranteed constraints: b.length = a.length

This is my code:

```
boolean solution(int[] a, int[] b) {
    
    int count = 0;
    ArrayList<Integer> tempa = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<Integer> tempb = new ArrayList<>();
    
    for(int i = 0; i < a.length; i++){
        if(a[i]!=b[i]){
            
            count++;
            
            tempa.add(a[i]);
            tempb.add(b[i]);
        }
        
    }
    
    if(count==0||(count==2 && tempa.get(0)==tempb.get(1) && tempa.get(1)==tempb.get(0))){
        return true;
    } else return false;
}
```

This code gave correct results for the following arrays:

a: [1, 2, 3]
b: [1, 2, 3]

a: [1, 2, 3]
b: [2, 1, 3]

a: [1, 2, 2]
b: [2, 1, 1]

a: [1, 2, 1, 2]
b: [2, 2, 1, 1]

a: [1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1]
b: [2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1]

a: [1, 1, 4]
b: [1, 2, 3]

a: [1, 2, 3]
b: [1, 10, 2]

a: [2, 3, 1]
b: [1, 3, 2]

a: [2, 3, 9]
b: [10, 3, 2]

a: [832, 998, 148, 570, 533, 561, 894, 147, 455, 279]
b: [832, 570, 148, 998, 533, 561, 455, 147, 894, 279]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add this for diferent arrays length

```
if (a.length != b.length) return false;
```

And your if needs to use equals()

```
return count == 0 || (count == 2 && tempa.get(0).equals(tempb.get(1)) && tempa.get(1).equals(tempb.get(0)));
```

Comment: i missed out a given condition.   
in question, it guaranteed b.length = a.length

Comment: k but you still need to change your if to use equals when comparing objects

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example where it fails:

```
solution(new int[]{2, 3, 9}, new int[]{9, 3, 2, 5});
```

You should add a length equality check to your code, like this

```
static boolean solution(int[] a, int[] b) {
    if(a.length != b.length) {
        return false;
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: i missed out a given condition. in question, it guaranteed b.length = a.length